# Formatting rule to have blank line between class member declarations

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, editorconfig

Micrsoft provides bunch of coding settings for EditorConfig 
[.NET coding convention settings for EditorConfig](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/editorconfig-code-style-settings-reference?view=vs-2017)

But cannot find the way to create a rule, which will suggest developer to add empty line between class members declaration.

```
// "Bad" style
public class Order
{
    private readonly IRepository _repository;
    private readonly IPriceCalculator _priceCalculator;
    public Order(IRepository repository, IPriceCalculator priceCalculator)
    {
        _repostitory = repository;
        _priceCalculator = priceCalculator;
    }
    public CopyFrom(Order originalOrder)
    {
        // Create new order
    }
    public Cancel(Customer customer)
    {
        // Cancel order
    }
}

// Good style
public class Order
{
    private readonly IRepository _repository;

    private readonly IPriceCalculator _priceCalculator;

    public Order(IRepository repository, IPriceCalculator priceCalculator)
    {
        _repostitory = repository;
        _priceCalculator = priceCalculator;
    }

    public CopyFrom(Order originalOrder)
    {
        // Create new order
    }

    public Cancel(Customer customer)
    {
        // Cancel order
    }
}
```

Comment: You can create a `DiagnosticAnalyzer` + `CodeFixProvider`.

Comment: Such a formatting option has never existed.  Most basic hangup is that it requires a parser, but the editor uses a lexical analyzer.  Parsers are difficult to implement properly since they can't handle syntax errors very well in a curly-brace language.  Always a lot of those around while you're busy typing in code.  Resharper tends to be standard advise, but [I don't see it](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/EditorConfig_CSHARP_BlankLinesPageScheme.html) try to tackle this either.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Visual Studio's [.NET coding convention settings for EditorConfig](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/editorconfig-code-style-settings-reference?view=vs-2017#formatting-conventions) don't provide a code style setting for that,
neither does the [EditorConfig itself](https://editorconfig.org/#supported-properties).

So using EditorConfig only, there is no way to create such a rule.

You might consider using StyleCop for this.

StyleCop was originally developed by Microsoft. The tool implements the code style guidelines as Microsoft defined them for the C# language. Now the development continues as open source.

[StyleCop](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers) is available as a code analyzer (e.g. via [this NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/StyleCop.Analyzers/)), so you can even configure it for your projects and solutions independently. Of course, you can store the configuration in your repositories to synchronize the settings across all developers. The configuration is stored in a `.ruleset` file, the file format is natively supported by Visual Studio.

You could also use StyleCop as a Visual Studio Extension (StyleCop Classic), but I would not recommend doing that.

For your use case, the rule [SA1513](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/blob/master/documentation/SA1513.md) is of interest.

> **Cause**
>   A closing brace within a C# element, statement, or expression is not followed by a blank line.

In general, there are lots of rules in StyleCop that improve the code readability and structure. You are free to choose those rules that suit your needs.

Comment: Is it still impossible to do so now (2022 july) ?

Comment: Just as an addition: don't use ruleset anymore, as StyleCop.Analyzers now also supports .editorconfig. So the rule would be `dotnet_diagnostic.SA1513.severity = warning`

Answer (score 0):

SA1513 in StyleCop is the one that worked for me